# Visual Source Safe: get versions where a specific line has changed

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to run down when a particular bug was created, but wading through the history is pretty time consuming. Is anyone familiar with a command line method to get a list of revisions where a line or range of lines changed?

**svn and vault evangelists:** I know, right....but you can't always pick the environment....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SourceSafe has an easy way to do this.. but I haven't used SourceSafe since version 2005.  One method you could try is using a divide and conquer search.

First, pick a date in way in the future, if the bug is there, double the length, until you find a version without the bug.

You just need two known points to work with, one when you know the bug is there, and one where you know the bug isn't there, cut those two in half and check the version in the middle.  if the bug is there cut the top half in half, if its not cut the bottom half into half.
This will be way more effective then looking in every file version.

I don't remember if SourceSafe has a version number for each file, if not you could just use the scrollbar as your guide for where the halfway point is.

Comment: VSS certainly has it's limits. Thanks for taking the time to answer.